# php check mysql wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i'm trying to create php code-but it's didn't work for me. It must check "post_title" in my site's database and then 'if exist {do} (while)'  if not exist create post.
please look at my code

```
?php
include 'wp-config.php';
$id = "id";
$nu = "2";
$selectquery ="SELECT * FROM `wpop_posts` WHERE `post_title` = '$id$nu' ";
$selectresult=mysql_query($selectquery);
    while(mysql_num_rows($selectresult)>0)
    {
        $errormsgnewemployee = '<p id=notification>it exist.</p>';
        echo "$errormsgnewemployee";
        ++$nu;
        echo" $nu";


   };
        if (!mysql_num_rows($selectresult)>0) {$my_post = array();
                                $my_post['post_title'] = $id .$nu;
                            $my_post['post_content'] = $shelma;
                                    $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
                            $my_post['post_author'] = 1;
                            $my_post['post_category'] = array(8,39); 
                            wp_insert_post( $my_post );
                                print 'thats good!';};





?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use raw SQL for this. Actually, there is already a function in Wordpress that will do exactly this: [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title). Simply pass the title as a string argument into the function and it will return the post object for the matching post. If multiple post share the same title it will simply return an array of posts.

Comment: no matter wordpress or joomla. i want to know how can i make it with raw SQL. it's for my experience.